# Updating a 2d table of counts

Tags: scala

Suppose I want a Scala data structure that implements a 2-dimensional table of counts that can change over time (i.e., individual cells in the table can be incremented or decremented). What should I be using to do this?

I could use a 2-dimensional array:

```
val x = Array.fill[Int](1, 2) = 0
x(1)(2) += 1
```

But Arrays are mutable, and I guess I should slightly prefer immutable data structures.

So I thought about using a 2-dimensional Vector:

```
val x = Vector.fill[Int](1, 2) = 0
// how do I update this? I want to write something like val newX : Vector[Vector[Int]] = x.add((1, 2), 1)
// but I'm not sure how
```

But I'm not sure how to get a new vector with only a single element changed.

What's the best approach?

Comment: vector's `.update` method [is guaranteed](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) to be done in effectively constant time

Comment: @om-nom-nom - Albeit with a very, very large constant factor compared to changing a primitive in an array.  About 500x in my hands for a 100x100 `Array` / `Vector`, if you just want to update one random cell in the matrix over and over again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best depends on what your criteria are.  The simplest immutable variant is to use a map from (Int,Int) to your count:

```
var c = (for (i <- 0 to 99; j <- 0 to 99) yield (i,j) -> 0).toMap
```

Then you access your values with `c(i,j)` and set them with `c += ((i,j) -> n)`; `c += ((i,j) -> (c(i,j)+1))` is a little bit annoying, but it's not too bad.

Faster is to use nested `Vector`s--by about a factor of 2 to 3, depending on whether you tend to re-set the same element over and over or not--but it has an ugly update method:

```
var v = Vector.fill(100,100)(0)
v(82)(49)     // Easy enough
v = v.updated(82, v(82).updated(49, v(82)(49)+1)    // Ouch!
```

Faster yet (by about 2x) is to have only one vector which you index into:

```
var u = Vector.fill(100*100)(0)
u(82*100 + 49)    // Um, you think I can always remember to do this right?
u = u.updated(82*100 + 49, u(82*100 + 49)+1)       // Well, that's actually better
```

If you don't need immutability and your table size isn't going to change, just use an array as you've shown.  It's ~200x faster than the fastest vector solution if all you're doing is incrementing and decrementing an integer.

Comment: Looks like this is the case [David Maclver talked about](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/08/functional-code-not-equal-good-code/)

Comment: @om-nom-nom - No, he was saying functional isn't automatically better.  This is showing that immutable isn't automatically better.  Normally the two go hand-in-hand, but they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in a very general and functional (but not necessarily performant) way, you can use lenses. Here's an example of how you could use [Scalaz 7](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)'s implementation, for example:

```
import scalaz._

def at[A](i: Int): Lens[Seq[A], A] = Lens.lensg(a => a.updated(i, _), (_(i)))
def at2d[A](i: Int, j: Int) = at[Seq[A]](i) andThen at(j)
```

And a little bit of setup:

```
val table = Vector.tabulate(3, 4)(_ + _)

def show[A](t: Seq[Seq[A]]) = t.map(_ mkString " ") mkString "\n"
```

Which gives us:

```
scala> show(table)
res0: String = 
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

We can use our lens like this:

```
scala> show(at2d(1, 2).set(table, 9))
res1: String = 
0 1 2 3
1 2 9 4
2 3 4 5
```

Or we can just get the value at a given cell:

```
scala> val v: Int = at2d(2, 3).get(table)
v: Int = 5
```

Or do a lot of more complex things, like apply a function to a particular cell:

```
scala> show(at2d(2, 2).mod(((_: Int) * 2), table))
res8: String = 
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 8 5
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in method for this, perhaps because it would require the Vector to know that it contains Vectors, or Vectors or Vectors etc, whereas most methods are generic, and it would require a separate method for each number of dimensions, because you need to specify a co-ordinate arg for each dimension.

However, you can add these yourself; the following will take you up to 4D, although you could just add the bits for 2D if that's all you need:

```
object UpdatableVector {
  implicit def vectorToUpdatableVector2[T](v: Vector[Vector[T]]) = new UpdatableVector2(v)
  implicit def vectorToUpdatableVector3[T](v: Vector[Vector[Vector[T]]]) = new UpdatableVector3(v)
  implicit def vectorToUpdatableVector4[T](v: Vector[Vector[Vector[Vector[T]]]]) = new UpdatableVector4(v)

  class UpdatableVector2[T](v: Vector[Vector[T]]) {
    def updated2(c1: Int, c2: Int)(newVal: T) =
      v.updated(c1, v(c1).updated(c2, newVal))
  }

  class UpdatableVector3[T](v: Vector[Vector[Vector[T]]]) {
    def updated3(c1: Int, c2: Int, c3: Int)(newVal: T) =
      v.updated(c1, v(c1).updated2(c2, c3)(newVal))
  }

  class UpdatableVector4[T](v: Vector[Vector[Vector[Vector[T]]]]) {
    def updated4(c1: Int, c2: Int, c3: Int, c4: Int)(newVal: T) =
      v.updated(c1, v(c1).updated3(c2, c3, c4)(newVal))
  }
}
```

In Scala 2.10 you don't need the implicit defs and can just add the `implicit` keyword to the class definitions.

Test:

```
  import UpdatableVector._

  val v2 = Vector.fill(2,2)(0)
  val r2 = v2.updated2(1,1)(42)
  println(r2) // Vector(Vector(0, 0), Vector(0, 42))

  val v3 = Vector.fill(2,2,2)(0)
  val r3 = v3.updated3(1,1,1)(42)
  println(r3) // etc
```

Hope that's useful.