# How do I create multidimensional Vectors in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to work with an immutable indexed multidimensional array. The structure that makes sense is a `Vector` of `Vector`s.

```
scala> val v = Vector[Vector[Int]](Vector[Int](1,2,3), Vector[Int](4,5,6), Vector[Int](7,8,9))
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Vector[Int]] = Vector(Vector(1, 2, 3), Vector(4, 5, 6), Vector(7, 8, 9))
```

It would be nice to create an empty array just by specifying the dimensions, like you can with `Array.ofDim`.

```
scala> a = Array.ofDim[Int](3,3)
a: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0))
```

However, there is no `Vector.ofDim`, function, and I can't find an equivalent.

Is there an equivalent of `Array.ofDim` for immutable objects? If not, why not?

Comment: It's for a program that solves Sudoku puzzles. A partial solution is represented as an nxn array of `Option[Int]`. Given a partial solution _p_, the program can hypothesize another one _p'_ by putting integers into the array. Because each _p_ may generate multiple _p'_ s, I want each partial solution to be immutable. My options appear to either be 1) represent the numbers with a private `Array` 2) represent the numbers with a `Vector`. (2) seems more in the functional style, but creating `Vector`s of `Vector`s is awkward.

Comment: You can represent multi-dimensional arrays/lists using single dimensions.

Comment: Prepare for some fun trying to update cells in a multi-dimensional Vector. Probably easiest is to have a utility method: `def update[T](v: Vector[Vector[T]])(c1: Int, c2: Int)(newVal: T) = v.updated(c1, v(c1).updated(c2, newVal))`. Or if you need higher dimensions copy and paste from http://stackoverflow.com/a/12612908/770361.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Each standard collection class has a companion object with factory methods, including `fill`. By example:

```
Vector.fill(3, 3)( 0 )
```

See [the relevant scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector$.html#fill[A](n1:Int,n2:Int)(elem:=>A):CC[CC[A]]).

Comment: Link gives 404. The current link is (2016-11-25): http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html

Comment: I updated the link (it was just badly parsed by SO). It turns out that the current scaladoc still does not mention `fill` so I've stuck to scala 2.9.1.

Comment: Not sure why you can't see it, but `fill` is there, and has been for a long while: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector$.html#fill[A](n1:Int,n2:Int)(elem:=>A):CC[CC[A]] It's in the companion object, of course

Comment: Oh scratch that, you're right. I was pretty sure to have clicked on the big icon to go to the object's page so I don't know how I missed it. Thanks, I'll point to the new docs then.

Answer (score 15):

There is a creation method called `tabulate` that lets you set the contents based on the index:

```
scala> Vector.tabulate(3,3){ (i,j) => 3*i+j+1 }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] =
Vector(Vector(1, 2, 3), Vector(4, 5, 6), Vector(7, 8, 9))
```

If you just need zeros (or some other constant), you can use `fill` instead:

```
scala> Vector.fill(3,3)(0)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] =
Vector(Vector(0, 0, 0), Vector(0, 0, 0), Vector(0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fill`:

```
scala> Vector.fill( 3 )( Vector.fill(3)(0) )
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = 
        Vector(Vector(0, 0, 0), Vector(0, 0, 0), Vector(0, 0, 0))
```